# Is is better to randomize result using MySQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, random

Is it better to return random rows using MySQL or PHP commands?

For example, I have a `product` table with 10 columns and 1000000 rows and want to return 10 random rows from it.

- Method 1 (let MySQL do most of the work):

  ```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id in (SELECT product_id FROM product ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)");
  while($results[] = mysql_fetch_row($query));
  ```
- Method 2 (let PHP do most of the work):

  ```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");
  while($results[] = mysql_fetch_row($query));
  shuffle($results);
  $results = array_slice($results, 0, 10);
  ```

Is method 1 or method 2 better?

Comment: Please consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq vs http://stackoverflow.com/faq for future questions along the lines of "which is better". However, in this case returning a result set that is larger than what you need can actually cause a memory_limit_exceeded error in PHP and cause major performance errors given a sufficiently large result set (and if one of those columns is a BLOB+ then that can quickly kill a script). If MySQL is not hosted on localhost then the network performance of numerous scripts in parallel are sufficient to DDOS yourself accidentally.

Comment: Testing yourself proves futile. RAND becomes a bottleneck. Never use it!

Answer (score 4):

it's best to let your MySQL do the work, there is no point in pulling out an entire database of items, just to discard everything but 10 things.

So your method 1:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id in (SELECT product_id FROM product ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)");
```

is what I would suggest using.

Comment: I would not go with `RAND` http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ read p.6

Comment: Yes, rand is a bottleneck, BUT the OP hasn't stated a more efficient way; Just asked the question which one to use?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs.  rand is a bottleneck for mysql and memory is the problem for php...I guess there isn't any perfect solution for this.  I guess I can get total rows in table and then use php to generate random to query database again

Answer (score 0):

I think MySQL way is better, because array with 1 million items is a really huge, there is no need to pass it in PHP.